# call to ReactJS component in Laravel blade templates

Tags: laravel, reactjs, laravel-blade

I use Laravel 5.4 and React 15.5.4, code is writing in ES6.

I'd like replace Vue and use React and I did it. But I often will use small components for example 2 in different places of blade template. I don't want use one app component.

I'd like use something like:

```
<span class="react">
<TestComponent property={true} />
</span>
```

I can't do it automatically. Now I use

```
<span data-component="TestComponent" data-props="{property:true}" />
```

and in app.js

```
_.each(document.querySelectorAll('[data-react]'), element => {
  let props ={};
  Array.prototype.slice.call(element.attributes)
  .forEach(item => {
    props[item.name] = item.value;
    if(item.name !== 'data-react'){
      element.removeAttribute(item.name);  
    }

  });
  ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(reactComponents[element.getAttribute('data-react')],props),element);
});
```

It works but I need to use add all properties to one react component property and then use for example `this.props.out.propery`

I also would like set normal component tag in my blade component

I've try to use in app.js

```
_.each(document.querySelectorAll('.react'), item => {  
  ReactDOM.render(item.children,item);
});
```

Someone have any idea to solve this problem?

---

**EDIT**

I changed my solution to:

```
<span data-react="LoginForm" input="{{json(request()->old())}}" error="{{session('error')}}" errors="{{json($errors->getMessages())}}" />
```

or

```
<LoginForm data-react="LoginForm" input="{{json(request()->old())}}" error="{{session('error')}}" errors="{{json($errors->getMessages())}}" />
```

in blade and in `resources/assets/js/app.js`

```
var reactComponents = {
  LoginForm: require('./components/login').default,
};
_.each(document.querySelectorAll('[data-react]'), element => {
  let props ={};
  Array.prototype.slice.call(element.attributes)
  .forEach(item => {
    props[item.name] = item.value;
  });
  ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(reactComponents[element.getAttribute('data-react')],props),element);
});
```

It works fine. This is not super clear solution but I have impression that the reasonable.
I can set components name in html code and add props almost same like in JSX.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can not mix JSX components directly with Blade templates. The only server side rendering available today for React is NodeJS.
What you could do to improve your architecture is add specific HTML tags with certain ids and render the react components in them. So inside Blade you could do something like:

```html
<div id="componentA"></div>
```

This will act as a place holder in your Blade template for that react component. Then you render your *componentA* from your app.js like this:

```html
React.render(<ComponentA prop1='valueX'/>, document.getElementById("componentA"))
```

Remember that in this case the world of react and world of Blade run at different times.

Comment: Thanks, I want to call to component name automatically and set props inside html tag. I added my solution in edit of my post

Answer (score 0):

You could use `document.getElementsByTagName('LoginForm')` getting all the instances and later iterate its attributes. It's clear code but not generic, because it will work just for LoginForm components.

If you want to render any tag name, then maybe it's better to use some attribute as you used with `data-react`.

getElementsByTagName isn't super supported by [old browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=getElementsByTagName) so maybe could a good idea to use jQuery as fallback `$('LoginForm')`